# Langevin equation with hydrodynamic interaction

Tags: fluid-dynamics, statistical-mechanics, differential-equations, stochastic-processes, non-equilibrium

We know Langevin equation in the presence of an external applied force is given by,
$$ m\frac{dv(t)}{dt} = -\gamma v(t) + \eta(t) + \vec{F} $$
where $\eta(t)$ is delta correlated stationary white noise.
We know there is no hydrodynamic interaction in the above equation. If there was such interaction then we would have got an extra term in the equation.
My questions are the following,

1. As far as Langevin dynamics, what is a $\textbf{hydrodynamic interaction}$ at the first place?
2. Can you provide me an explicit form of this force so that I can try to solve the 1D Langevin equation in presence of it ?

Comment: Where did you hear about this hydrodynamic interaction? Link, reference?

Comment: I heard about it in a seminar. I am attaching one Wikipedia link which  I found when I was searching for the answer. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stokesian_dynamics